# Undertsanding how interface works

Tags: android, interface, onclicklistener

How does `onClick` method gets fired when a user clicks a view, `OnclickListener` is an interface right? It doesn't define how a method works.

I understand that it gives the programmer the liberty to define it's own actions when `onClick` method is invoked but how is that method invoked when a user clicks a view? And *how does it work* when there are multiple methods in an *interface*?

I understand that its more of basic java question than an android question. But I really have had this doubt for a long time. Hope somehow explains me how it works.

```
     public interface OnClickListener 
     {         
     /**          
      * Called when a view has been clicked.          
      *          
      * @param v The view that was clicked.
      */         
     void onClick(View v);
     }
```

Comment: You may need to clarify what you're asking; at least I don't find it very clear. Are you asking how the elements call the handlers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same question when i start  learning android.It doesn't call directly  onClick method when the button is pressed. Every thing is done in the back by android.When we first call setOnclickListener it will set the information listener. Here you have the source code of the setOnClickListener method.

```
 public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) 
 {
     if (!isClickable()) 
    {

         setClickable(true);
     }
     getListenerInfo().mOnClickListener = l;
 }
```

And we have a method performAccessibilityActionInternal this is called when we press the screen  and if the action was click it will call performClick method and this perfromClick method will call the onClick method of the Listener 
Here is The performClick method

```
public boolean performClick() {
     final boolean result;
     final ListenerInfo li = mListenerInfo;
     if (li != null && li.mOnClickListener != null) {
         playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
         li.mOnClickListener.onClick(this);
         result = true;
     } else {
         result = false;
     }

     sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED);
     return result;
   }
```

For detail see the android open source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java#View.PerformClick)

Answer (score 0):

It is a callback mechanism. U need to define a concrete class that implements the OnclickListener interface. That is what you do when you setOnClickListener on the view like this

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Perform action on click   
                }
            });
```

You are defining an anonymous innerclass that implements OnClickInterface.
You can also define another Custom class that implements the OnClickInterface and just set that class in the setOnClickListener.

When you set the listener, for understanding you can visualize that button will have a reference to your class inside it

Eg:

```
public class Button extends TextView {
     OnClickInterface mCallBack;

     void setOnClickListener (OnClickInterface in) {
       mCallBack = in;
     }
     void clicked(){
      in.onClick(this);
     }
}
```

Whenever the button is clicked, it just calls the onclick method of your interface implementation giving it the view

Hope It Helps

Answer (score 0):

An interface in Java is a contract, it contains signatures of methods that classes that want to support the contract have to implement.

```
 public interface OnClickListener 
 {              
      void onClick(View v);
 }
```

A class that implements `OnClickListener` has to implement the method `onClick(View v)`. for example -

```
public class LogListener implements OnClickListener
{              
    private final Logger logger;

    LogListener(Logger logger) { this.logger = logger; }

    void onClick(View v) { logger.log("View Clicked!"); }
}
```

An interface cannot be constructed, it can only reference an instance of an implementation of the interface -

```
OnClickListener listener = new LogListener(logger);
```

When `listener.onClick` is called, the implementation of the referenced object is fetched in runtime - in this case `LogListener.onClick`.

The Android Framework wants to support a way that views will alert that they have been clicked so the programmer will be able to handle clicks, so they provide a method `setOnClickListener` that gets any object that implements OnClickListener keeps a reference to it, and when the button is clicked the onClick method is called.

This pattern is called [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).